# How to edit a file with shell scripting

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a file containing thousands of lines like this:

`0x7f29139ec6b3: W 0x7fff06bbf0a8` 
`0x7f29139f0010: W 0x7fff06bbf0a0` 
`0x7f29139f0014: W 0x7fff06bbf098` 
`0x7f29139f0016: W 0x7fff06bbf090` 
`0x7f29139f0036: R 0x7f2913c0db80`

I want to make a new file which contains only the second hex number on each line (the part marked in bold above)

I have to put all these hex numbers in an array in a C program. So I am trying to make a file with only the hex numbers on the right hand side, so that my C program can use the `fscanf` function to read these numbers from the modified file.

I guess we can use some shell script to make a file containing those hex numbers? grep or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep -oP` command:

```
grep -oP ' \K0x[a-fA-F0-9]*' file
0x7fff06bbf0a8
0x7fff06bbf0a0
0x7fff06bbf098
0x7fff06bbf090
0x7f2913c0db80
```

Comment: This is true, but why do you need a custom field separator? Why not write `awk '{print $3}' file` (or `cut -f 3 file`)?

Comment: @anubhava , Yes it works. But I have a small problem here still. I have some lines like:0x7f29139f0018: W 0x7fff06bbf088
0x7f29139f001a: W 0x7fff06bbf080
0x7f29139f001c: W 0x7fff06bbf078  
0x7f29139f0036: R 0x7f2913c0db80
0x7f29139f003d: W 0x7f2913c0dcd8
0x7f29139f0047: R 0x7f2913c0dfb8   , so you see there are line with either 'W' or 'R'. THe first four lines i gave only had 'W'. But how to make this work for lines containing 'R' as well ??

Comment: Pls don't post data in comments, edit your question and post it there. Also you didn't tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed and edit inplace. For matching "R" or any other char use

> sed -i "s/.*:..//g" file
>
> ```
> cat file
> 0x7fff06bbf0a8
>
> 0x7fff06bbf0a0
>
> 0x7fff06bbf098
>
> 0x7fff06bbf090
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you always want to select the third field, the simplest approach is to use `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 3 file
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '{print $3}' file
```

Comment: `cut` does not split on whitespace by default.  If the separator is literally exactly one single space, then `cut -d' ' -f 3` will work, but just `cut -f 3` won't.

Comment: @MarkReed: Eep, you're right! Somehow I decided we were dealing with tabs. Will fix, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command on the file that will create a new file in the format you want: *somecommand* <*oldfile* >*newfile*.  That will leave the original file intact and create a new one for you to feed to your C program.

As to what *somecommand* should be, you have multiple options.  The easiest is probably `awk`:

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

But you can also do it with `sed` or `grep` or `perl` or `cut` ... see other answers for an embarrassment of choices.